# What is a waveform dictionary?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, definition, wavelets

If I google "waveform dictionary" or "waveform dictionaries" I find some papers that use these mathematical objects e.g. [The Analysis of Foreign Exchange Data Using Waveform Dictionaries](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=5944). For example, in the above-mentioned paper, we can read that

> A waveform dictionary is a class of transforms that generalizes both windowed Fourier transforms and wavelets

Anyway, a formal mathematical definition seems to be missing. What is a waveform dictionary? Is it a frame (i.e. the generalization of Riesz basis)? I think it is not a basis because it should be overcomplete. References, papers, solutions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The [abstract I found here](https://calendar.fiu.edu/event/introduction_to_riesz_bases_frames_and_waveform_dictionaries_with_dr_pierluigi_vellucci) is the clearest explanation I was able to find. My best guess is that a waveform dictionary is a frame that is also closed under time and frequency shifts (just as a [Gabor system](https://math.gmu.edu/~dwalnut/teach/Math772/Fall07/772f07lec11.pdf) would be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking for the speaker giving the talk that I linked in my comment on your question, I was able to find [this Arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.11158) that gives the following explicit definition of a waveform dictionary.

> Let $\gamma = (t,\xi ,u) \in \Gamma = \Bbb R_{>0} \times \Bbb R^2$. A *waveform dictionary* $\mathcal G$ is a collection of $L^2(\Bbb R)$ functions of the form
> $$
> G_\gamma(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{t}} g\left(\frac{x-u}{t}\right)e^{2 \pi i \xi x},
> $$
> where $g \in L^2(\Bbb R)$ is called the *window function* that satisfies $\|g\|_{L^2(\Bbb R)} = 1, g(0) \neq 0,$ and the integral of $g$ is non-zero. The function $G_\gamma$ is known as a *time-frequency atom*.

In comparison to a [Gabor system](https://math.gmu.edu/%7Edwalnut/teach/Math772/Fall07/772f07lec11.pdf), we act on the window function not only with time-shift and frequency-shift operators, but also with some kind of "time dilation" operator $f(x) \mapsto \frac 1{\sqrt{t}}f(x/t)$.

The paper also cites the following reference, which seems promising:

> *Ole Christensen et al. An introduction to frames and Riesz bases, volume 7. Springer, 2003.*

Comment: Thus, like the Gabor system, it could be a frame. I mean, $(t,\xi,u)\in\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb R^2$, it is surely a frame for $L^2(\mathbb R)$. Am I right? Thank you!

Comment: @Mark Keep in mind that a Gabor system is a countable set whereas a waveform dictionary seems to be uncountable. That said, I suspect that if you look at the analogous construction (i.e. taking $t,\xi,u$ to be integer multiples of some predetermined real numbers) then you indeed could end up with a frame